# How to detect phrases from an English sentence.

Tags: nlp, text-mining, preprocessing

The question is not about *detecting keyphrases*. It is about detecting a combination of words makes a valid phrase or not. For example,

> "John reads New York Times in New York."

Here, the phrases are

> New York Times
>
> New York

Detecting *keyword phrases* is a **Text Summarization** problem, however, here it is classifying whether a combination of words make a valid phrase or not.

There have been a few algorithms we have gone through including but not limited to **models.phrases – Phrase (collocation) detection** of **Gensim**, however, we are looking for better results.

Comment: Have you tried detecting n-grams and then performing summarisation?

Comment: Interesting proposition. Will try and update the results here.

Comment: A common practice is to detect n-grams lets say New York, New Delhi etc. and then replace them with New_York and New_Delhi etc. so that it appears as a single token, and the summarisation algorithm treats it that way.

Answer (score 4):

The name for what you want to do is `Named Entity Recognition (NER)`.  There are several great software packages for this, namely:

- [Stanford NER](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)
- [MIT's Information Extractor](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE)
- [spaCy](https://spacy.io/)

Comment: Not really, the phrases does not always need to be Named Entities. For example, foot_soldier.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Stanford Parser for recognizing the phrases. It is a tool that recognizes the grammatical structure of sentences and actually performs syntactic analysis. It has available libraries in java, python, php, Ruby, C# (I guess at least one of those will work for you). I had used it in Java couple of years back and I was very happy with its accuracy.

You can find out more about it [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#About), and it also allows you to try it online through [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) link (it is currently now but it's normally working).

Comment: I have already used StanfordNLP, want a better accuracy than that.